# What factors determine the direction of the resultant force vector?

Tags: aerodynamics, lift, drag

The overall aerodynamic force acting on a wing that is creating lift is not straight upward but is inclined backward. We usually consider the vertical and horizontal axes of the force separately. Lift is defined as the portion of the resultant force that is perpendicular to the relative wind, and induced drag is the portion parallel with it. The slope of the angle of the resultant force is the L/D ratio. This ratio changes with angle of attack as shown in the following diagram. As the AoA increases this vector leans further back creating a different L/D ratio (more drag for the same amount of lift).

[image]

Then looking from the wing's point of view, the portion of the RF perpendicular to the chord is the normal force (N) and the part parallel to it is the axial force (A). We can see that the the angle of the RF with respect to the wing chord is less affected by changes in AoA.

[image]

I've never seen a chart that graphs out the N/A relationship. Does this ratio change at all with AoA or is it a fixed property of the wing design? If it is not fixed, what dynamic factors (speed, AoA, etc.) affect the direction of the resultant force?

Comment: R = L + D, should be basic vector math.

Comment: @RonBeyer ??  R *squared* = L *squared* + D *squared*.  I'm not asking about the trigonometry. I'm asking about the physics of induced drag.

Comment: @RonBeyer I re-worded it. Maybe it makes more sense what I'm asking.

Comment: @TomMcW your drawings are a bit misleading. In the first two diagrams, you set your R force perpendicular to the wing chord. In the last diagram, you set it at an angle. These diagrams do not represent an equivalent situation, is this intentional?

Comment: @sanchises No. It's not intentional that it appears perpendicular. The angles are really exaggerated. The lift force is generally a lot higher than the drag force but if I tried to graph it at all accurately the angles would be too small to see.

Comment: @sanchises I had actually made the top drawings a long time ago for another answer

Comment: OK perhaps you ought to exaggerate the drag force in the first two drawings too  then to make sure it's clear what you're asking.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I've edited your images to make them a bit smaller. My understanding: This force (*total aerodynamic force*) is the result of the difference of pressure between the airfoil sides and the reaction to the downwash created by this pressure difference. Resolution into lift and induced drag is then purely arbitrary, these forces have no reality per se. The direction thus depends on the factors creating pressure (e.g. Bernoulli's principle) and reaction (Newton's 3rd law of motion). [Related](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/presar.html).

Comment: @TomMcW The change in resultant in N/A will be the same as that of the resultant vector in L/D case- they're the same. You're seeing difference because in case of the L/D case, the angle of attack gets added to the change. The only difference is that the co-ordinate system is changed. For L/D case, the angle of attack, alpha, gets added progressively to the resultant vector.

Comment: @mins Thanks for the edit. I am stuck using my phone for all this and with the apps I use I can never figure out how to reduce the size. Several months ago I came to that realization that lift and induced drag were the same force broken down into axes that make sense to he pilot.

Comment: @aeroalias I was reading a paper on the net that was showing from the chord axis and it seemed in the author's drawings that the angle was very close to the same for different AoA's. I didn't know of it was just an artifact of having to cheat the angles to make a usable diagram butI started to wonder if it was static. After hours of insomniac calculations and reading last night I came to the conclusion that L/D and N/A moved proportionately but the N/A just had the AoA subtracted from it.

Comment: @aeroalias But mathematically it is possible for them to move in opposite directions. For example, at 0° AoA they are the same. But if at 3° AoA the L/D shifts back 5° when you subtract the AoA, the N/A vector shifts *forward*. I'm not sure if that behavior actually occurs. That's sort of what the question is about. Looking at things from the perspective of the chord can help me understand some of the physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the resulting force is not perpendicular to the wing's chord but can point either way, slightly forward and backward. The very first polar charts which were published show this nicely, because those plots were true polar plots and used the wing chord as the reference orientation for 0°.

[image: Illustration on page 196 of Otto Lilienthal's "Der Vogelflug als Grundlage der Fliegekunst"]

Illustration on page 196 of Otto Lilienthal's "Der Vogelflug als Grundlage der Fliegekunst" showing measurements on model wings as polar plots ([source](http://www.museumnet.lilienthal-museum.de/digitalisate/gl_10.pdf)). Note the left part: Here the forces are plotted in the wing section's coordinate system.

The N/A relationship was covered by the work of Edward C. Polhamus, who did a lot of research on this at NACA Langley and published several papers with equations for [calculating the leading edge thrust](http://www.pdas.com/refs/tp1500.pdf), the force which helps to tilt the resultant force vector forward.

Comment: While I don't have the required background to develop, I feel the induced angle of attack, resulting from the downwash, which creates the induced drag (which in turn makes the difference between the lift component and the whole aerodynamic force) is a main point of the answer. `ai(y0)=atan{-w(y0)/V∞}` seems the equation that defines this difference, as published [here](http://www.heliciel.com/en/helice/calcul-helice-aile/Theorie-%20ligne%20portante-Prandtl.htm). See [also](http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~lutze/AOE3104/airfoilwings.pdf).

Comment: @mins Sheesh, I'll have to delve into peter's and your links when I've had more sleep! When we say it's the *downwash* that creates the induced drag I always feel that the term is a little confusing. If you look at it in Newtonian terms the drag portion of the angle must be caused by "forward-wash." In other words the wing imparts momentum to the air not only downward but slightly forward. It's the same movement of air, like you said in your other comment, but the word *downwash* was a point of confusion for me when I was trying to understand induced drag.

Comment: @Peter I don't speak German so I used Google Translate on the labels. Did the best I could with the results it gave me. Let me know if something could be worded better. I couldn't figure out where "normal" was supposed to go in that one label. The sentence Google gave me didn't make sense. Oddly enough, that's the only word on the page that's the same in both languages but I couldn't figure out the grammar.

Comment: @TomMcW: Thanks a lot for the edit! Normal means perpendicular, this is for the 90° vector only. What probably also needs explaining is the "rotierend gemessen" part. Lilienthal used a special machine which swung small wings around on a horizontal arm as a poor man's wind tunnel, and that is where the results are from.

Comment: @TomMcW: The downwash starts by the tip vortexes, the air going from the bottom side to the up side of the wing. So the downwash isn't anyway a simple move downwards. You'll find such elements in the links provided.

Answer (score 1):

The angle of attack changes the L/D ratio, yes. Image the angle increased to 90 degrees (coming straight from the bottom). I suppose you could call that 100% lift and 0% drag.

Not sure how useful that is... From another point of view, that's 100% drag and 0% lift. [Pugachev's Cobra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pugachev%27s_Cobra).

Comment: This answers the first question, "Does this ratio change at all with AoA or is it a fixed property of the wing design?" This doesn't anwer the second part of the question, "If it is not fixed, what dynamic factors (speed, AoA, etc.) affect the direction of the resultant force?".